# Can someone explain this javascript code I took from MDM web docs?

Tags: javascript, callback, higher-order-functions

I understand everything about this code (or at least I thought I did) except the fact that it includes the number "2" in the new filtered array. I know the code is supposed to return all prime numbers but if (num % i == 0) { return false }, shouldn't that make it so that it skips the number "2"?

```
const array = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];

function isPrime(num) {
  for (let i = 2; num > i; i++) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return num > 1;
}

console.log(array.filter(isPrime)); // [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `for` loop, the variable `i` starts from `2`, and the condition checks whether `num > i`, therefore the `for` loop never executes if `num` equals `2`.

However, `2` is included in the final result because of the final statement `return num > 1` (since `2` is greater than `1`).

Answer (score 0):

Now is a good time to start familiarizing yourself with the use of a debugger.  Using a debugger you can step through the code line by line as it executes, observing the exact runtime behavior and the changing values of the variables as each operation is executed.

When you do this, you'll note that for the value of `2` this line of code is never reached:

```
if (num % i == 0) {
```

Note the conditions in the `for` loop:

```
for (let i = 2; num > i; i++) {
```

So when `num` is `2` the loop is never entered (because `num > i` is `false` right away) and the control moves on to the next operation.  And that next operation returns `true`:

```
return num > 1;
```